# Curious as to why my constructors don't seem to be working

Tags: c++, constructor

The following is how I was taught to use constructors, and it seems to work for one variable, but when I use a few it seems to act odd.

I'm not too sure what to do to fix this, but I would like some direction. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Numbers
{
public:
    Numbers (int a, int b, int c)
    {
        setNum (a);
        setNum (b);
        setNum (c);
    }

    void setNum (int x, int y, int z)
    {
        numbers = x;
        digits = y;
        numerals = z;
    }

    int getNum ()
    {
        return numbers;
        return digits;
        return numerals;
    }

    int add (int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int answer = x + y + z;
        return answer;
    }

private:
    int numbers;
    int digits;
    int numerals;
};

int main ()
{
    Numbers numbersobject (12,13,14);
    cout << numbersobject.getNum () << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many arguments does `setNum` take? How many do you pass when you call it? And what do you think will happen at the first`return` statement in `getNum`?

Comment: You can only return one thing from a function at a time.

Comment: See also initialization list for the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd meaning compile error?!

In the constructor, look at your `setNum`, it must take 3 parameters. You probably need

```
setNum(a,b,c);
```

And you CANNOT return 3 elements in `getNum`, using 3 `return` statements. If you need to return more than 2 elements, use `std::tuple`, or `std::pair` for 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your constructor to use a [member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

```
Numbers (int a, int b, int c)
: numbers {a}, digits {b}, numerals {c} {}
```

Or the older version

```
Numbers (int a, int b, int c)
{
    numbers = a;
    digits = b;
    numerals = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simplify your constructor

```
class Numbers
{
  public:  
    Numbers(int a, int b, int c)
    : numbers(a), digits(b), numerals(c) // Initialization list
    { ; }
    //...
};
```

In your simple class, there is no need for the constructor to call a setter function.